# Big Cartel change 'Sold out' to 'Sold'

Tags: bigcartel

I need help for my big cartel shop www.muetos.de.
the question is 
where to find the 
'Sold Out' 
in big cartels code 
and how can I change it to 
'sold'?

thanks!
best,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Go into Advanced editing under Products and look for the part "span class="status" Sold Out" and change Sold Out to just Sold. Then under Product section "data-sold-title="Sold out" and change to sold. Finally, under Home section, it is "span class="status" Sold Out" and change to sold. So it is in 3 places you have to change it.